# "Missing columns in relationship" when creating table

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have tried to create three tables(CUSTOMERS, VEHICLES and RENTALS), the third table (RENTALS) has foreign keys referring to the two primary keys of the first two tables (CUSTOMERS and RENTALS). When creating this third table I get an error  **Missing columns in relationship(Rel=CUSTOMERS[[]] -> RENTALS[[]])**

Here's my codes

```
     private void createTables() throws SQLException {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(custNumber AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "firstName VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, surname VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, idNum INTEGER NOT NULL, phoneNum INTEGER NOT NULL, canRent BIT NOT NULL)");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE VEHICLES(vehNumber AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, make VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, " +
            "category VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, rentalPrice FLOAT NOT NULL, availableForRent BIT NOT NULL)");
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE RENTALS(rentalNumber AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, dateRental VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, dateReturned VARCHAR(155) NOT NULL, " +
            "pricePerDay FLOAT NOT NULL, totalRental FLOAT NOT NULL, custNumber INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(custNumber), " +
            "vehNumber INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES VEHICLES(vehNumber))");

        System.out.println("Database populated");
     }
```

and here's the error
[image]

Your help will be very much appreciated, I have looked around but found nothing that helps.

Comment: Post code as text, not images.

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Access, an AutoNumber field (DDL: `AUTOINCREMENT` or `COUNTER`) is a "Long Integer".

In UCanAccess DDL, `INTEGER` creates an "Integer" (16-bit) field and `LONG` creates a "Long Integer" (32-bit) field.

You need to declare your foreign key columns as `LONG`, not `INTEGER`.