# UCanAccess - How to create a VARCHAR foreign key in MS Access? Getting "Missing columns in relationship" error

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I'm trying to create a master/detail relationship between two tables in MS Access using the UCanAccess JDBC driver.

Both tables get created but the foreign key relationship fails with "**Missing columns in relationship(Rel=master_table[[]] -> detail_table[[]])**".

Here is my test code:

```
try  {

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE master_table ("
                        + "masterPK VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL"
                        + ");");

    statement.execute("CREATE TABLE detail_table ("
                        + "detailPK LONG PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                        + "detailFK VARCHAR(32) REFERENCES master_table(masterPK) NOT NULL"
                        + ");");

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.getMessage();
}
```

The statements work fine when I issue them inside Access, but not via UCanAccess.  What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using different alpha and numeric data types, with and without size specifications, to no avail.

I also read with interest ["Missing columns in relationship" when creating table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207198/missing-columns-in-relationship-when-creating-table) and tried the example after changing the foreign keys to LONG.  That didn't work, either.

I'm using UCanAccess 4.0.4, MS Access (2007-2016 file format), OpenJDK 13+33 and OpenJFX 13.0.1, running in Apache NetBeans 11.1 on Windows 10.

If it helps, the SQLException message is as follows:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing columns in
>   relationship(Rel=master_table[[]] -> detail_table[[]])    at
>   com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.RelationshipCreator.validate(RelationshipCreator.java:183)
>     at
>   com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.RelationshipCreator.createRelationship(RelationshipCreator.java:98)
>     at
>   com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.RelationshipBuilder.toRelationship(RelationshipBuilder.java:192)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.Persist2Jet.createForeignKey(Persist2Jet.java:807)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.Persist2Jet.createForeignKeys(Persist2Jet.java:761)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.converters.Persist2Jet.createTable(Persist2Jet.java:481)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.commands.CreateTableCommand.persist(CreateTableCommand.java:100)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:323)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:205)
>     at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:273)
>     at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Execute.execute(Execute.java:44)     at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:157)
>     at
>   replicatesqliteschema.ReplicateSQLiteSchema.createContent(ReplicateSQLiteSchema.java:190)
>     at
>   replicatesqliteschema.ReplicateSQLiteSchema.start(ReplicateSQLiteSchema.java:271)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
>     at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native
>   Method)   at
>   javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue with console.bat. Results [here](https://pastebin.com/vYwJ6xNx). Please try doing the same console.bat test on your machine and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Gord. I did more tests in the console - using Java8 1.8.0_231, a 2007 accdb and an antique MDB - the relationship still isn't being created in the CREATE TABLE statement. However, it works with ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT. Also, I just booted my old Windows 7 Pro 64-bit PC. It works fine with OpenJDK11 and a 2007 accdb ==> it must be something in my Win10 config. I shall investigate. Any clues where to look? And thanks for your help. It's much appreciated. UCanAccess is an excellent tool and I would very much like to donate and use it if I can get it to work.